# Float HTML like PyGTK Container

Tags: python-2.7, pygtk

I'm making an application using Python and PyGTK. The application consists basically in a disc catalog where the covers are shown. My question is: Is there any container that supports a behaviour like the float HTML style?

I want a container where I can add the covers and it "does the math" to know the position of each one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GtkIconView or GtkGrid.

A demo of album covers Using Grid can be found here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mUcExd9oDH4

Comment: Hi, I think the GtkGrid is what I'm looking for, but can I use it in GTK 2? I'm asking because I can't find any documentation about it [here](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/).

Comment: Hi again, I did some tests with the IconView and it solves my problem. Thanks ;-)